# How to specify minimal value for fractionDigits restriction in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have a following XML Schema:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="fractionalSalary">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" />
        <xsd:minExclusive value="0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Is there any option to specify minimal number of `xsd:fractionDigits` to 2? Because I have a following restriction for salary: `positive number with 2 decimal places precision, e.g. 10000.50` and validation should fail on inputs like `1000.5452` or `14582.0001` but also on input `1000.5` or `10000`.

PS: Using XML Schema 1.0

Comment: That's an exact number of fractional digits, not minimal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a pattern restriction:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="fractionalSalary">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" />
        <xsd:minExclusive value="0" />
        <xsd:pattern value="\d+\.\d{2}" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This means that the decimal supplied must match the regex.

At this point, you can probably get rid of the fractionDigits element too, as that constraint is covered by the regex.